# OpenTissue boost bindings issue

Tags: c++, svn, boost, cmake

I want to install OpenTissue physics simulation library, and it requires boost. 
There is a .bat file in the third_party/include directory which retrieves the required boost bindings. I've successfully ran the script and after that CMake. 
However, the CMake 'Configure' states: "Could NOT find boost", even though it is in the directory where the authors of the script supposed it would be. After that, I've tried to manually set the BOOST_BINDING_PATH, as stated here: http://www.opentissue.org/mediawiki/index.php/Boost_bindings. But still, I cannot get the CMake to register the boost bindings.

Has anyone done this successfully?

OS: Windows 8.1
OpenTissue retrieved from: http://www.opentissue.org/svn/OpenTissue/sandbox
CMake: 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 1):

If you know where Boost is, you could pass `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR` when you run CMake, like so:

```
cmake -DBOOST_INCLUDE_DIR='path_to_boost_headers' -DBOOST_LIBRARY_DIR='path_to_boost_libraries'
```